# Node.JS - SQL server query with parameters to prevent SQL injection

Tags: node.js

Im using the following which works perfect when querying the database:

```
let conn = await sql.connect(process.env.connectionSetup)
    let recordset = await conn.query("select * from POLICIES where policyid=912")
    res.json(recordset)
```

The problem is when adding a parameter, to prevent SQL injection:

```
let conn = await sql.connect(process.env.connectionSetup)
    let recordset = await conn.query("select * from POLICIES where policyid=:policy", { policy: 912})
    res.json(recordset)
```

In that case, Im getting the error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near
> ':'.

I also tried utilizing ? but I get the same error. Does that have something to do with tedious?!

Thanks.

Comment: what SQL driver API do you use? is it SQL Server thru mssql ?

Comment: That's right PA.  const sql = require('mssql');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent *SQL injection attacks*, the safe way to insert values into an SQL query is using **SQL parameters**.

The actual syntax may vary depending on the SQL dialect your database uses and depending on the server driver API.

For nodejs `mssql`, you have **tagged template literals** in the form of

```
  sql.query`select * from POLICIES where policyid = ${policy}`
```

According to the mssql documentation

> All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection. This is because it is rendered as prepared statement, and thus all limitations imposed in MS SQL on parameters apply. e.g. Column names cannot be passed/set in statements using variables.

Comment: That works fantastically well. I will learn more about that method and SQL Injection. Thanks PA!

Answer (score 1):

U can use

```
var request =  new sql.Request();
request.input('policyid',sql.VarChar,policy);
request.query("select * from POLICIES where policyid = @policyid");
```

refer below links for more details

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value

Answer (score 0):

`select * from POLICIES where policyid = ${policy}` is just a string . This is not a request with params. If you do this you are open to sql injection.

Look this
https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/parameters.html